# Text editor for svg text

Tags: svg, wysiwyg, jquery-svg

I am currently working with svg and its dom manipulation... Are there any WYSIWYG editors for SVG text. I have browsed so much, but can find only editors for html text. If someone can suggest one it would be of great help to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have any specific recommendations, but googling for "svg wysiwyg" turns up many promising tools. Have you tried them all?

Comment: Though the post is old, it is suitable to be asked on [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An opensource and free editor for SVG is [inkscape](http://inkscape.org).

Other (proprietary) software includes,e.g., [Adobe Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/illustrator.html).

Answer (score 2):

- [inkscape](http://inkscape.org) : opensource, recommended by w3c.
- [svg-edit](https://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/) : JS based having many features. Try it [here](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.6/editor/svg-editor.html). It's perfect.
- [bluegriffon](http://www.bluegriffon.org./) : Another opensource editor. Not only for SVG but HTML5, CSS3, MathML etc
- [Sketsa](http://www.kiyut.com/products/sketsa/index.php) : It's not opensource. So less recommended. But have good features.

Comment: Adding to the list (if one prefers text-level editing + display), emacs - see http://tavmjong.free.fr/blog/?p=243.